# 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-database - Not found

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

Trying to learn how to use firebase with React, but getting a type error and I belive this is the cause. the node_modules folder seems to contain most of the firebase stuff but firebase-database is not one of them, despite it being in the firebase docs.

Not sure what to do.

tried `npm i @react-firebase/database` and 'npm install firebase-database'

Error: 
`TypeError: _firebase_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.database is not a function`

Comment: What exact ``TypeError`` did you get?

Comment: I get 'TypeError: _firebase_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.database is not a function'